# Dynamic gridview paging not working for second page or beyond

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Sorry for a possible duplicate question, but I am going crazy with this!

I have an asp gridview (gvResults) that has its data set dynamically from a sql query based on user choice. Here is the asp grideview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvResults" runat="server" Visible="False" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="1px" CssClass="gvClass" AllowPaging="True" HorizontalAlign="Left" OnPageIndexChanging="gvResults_PageIndexChanged" AllowSorting="True" ShowFooter="True">
```

Here is one of VB.NET code behind sql querys that puts data in a data table and then binds it to the grid view:

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim connString As String = "Data Source=SQL5\AX;Initial Catalog=PAR;User ID=XXXXX;Password=XXXXXXXXX"
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connString)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select current_status as Status, Count(current_status) As Total From tbl_PAR_Management Where current_status !='Closed' Group By current_status")
    Dim sqlDa As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    cmd.Connection = connection
    connection.Open()
    sqlDa.Fill(dt)
    gvResults.DataSource = dt
    gvResults.DataBind()
    connection.Close()
```

And here is what I am using to TRY and page to the next set of results:

```
Protected Sub gvResults_PageIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, e As GridViewPageEventArgs)
    gvResults.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    gvResults.DataBind()
End Sub
```

My problem is when I click page 2, or any other page number for that matter, the grid view turns off and I don't see any results from the query. What am i missing or doing wrong that this is happening?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your code in `gvResults_PageIndexChanged`.

Try putting the code in `gvResults_PageIndexChanging`.